# При использовании spring отпадает необходимость в Filter?

Tags: spring, java, веб-программирование

Я если честно и без Springa не видел мотива для себя их использовать.
Если да,то опишите ситуацию, пожалуйста

Comment: нет, ситуации теже, в чем ты видишь альтернативу в спринге?

Comment: Я надеялся. Если не сложно, можно небольшую ситуацию вне спринга, когда нужен фильтр? Стандартно: jsp отвечают за представление, на сервлеты наложу бизнес-логику и логику переходом, не тянутся руки к Filter

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, что тебе не понятно, спринг - это фреймворк для j2ee, фильтр - это класс в j2ee технологии

Comment: Это я понимаю. Со сприном понял, фильтр в силе. Не могу представить ситуацию, гдн мне понадобится фильтр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вопрос **об общем использовании фильтров**:

Фильтры полезны тогда, когда есть проверки, либо обработчики, которые нужны не в одном-двух сервлетах, а в нескольких сразу или даже во всём приложении.

Например, с помощью фильтров можно **проверять права доступа** к странице. Естественно, вы можете в каждый контроллер вставить такую проверку, но это приведёт к дублированию кода и увеличению его в размерах. Гораздо проще это сделать с помощью фильтров. Кроме того такая проверка на стороне очень хорошо согласуется с принципом единой ответственности, когда контроллер занимается только тем для чего он предназначен.

Ещё пример: **единый обработчик исключений**. Например, у вас есть REST-сервис и выхотите, чтобы исключения приводили к тому, что клиенту возвращается 500 статус и сообщение, закодированное в JSON. Добавлять try/catch в каждый сервлет быстро надоедает.

И ещё пример: вам необходимо **ограничить обращение к ресурсу**. Возможно, вы будете перенаправлять пользователя на специальную страницу, если он зашел в нерабочее время, либо вы захотите поставить лимит на количество запросов от клиента в минуту. Вся эта логика очень изящно выносится в фильтр и легко прикручивается к работающему приложению.

На вопрос об о том **может ли Spring заменить фильтры**:

Для некоторых из приведенных мной примеров Spring уже предоставляет готовые решения. Частично они основаны на этих же фильтрах (например, так работает Spring Security). Остальная же часть решается с помощью аспектно-ориентированного программирования (AOP).

Да, в большинстве случаев можно написать соответствующие аспекты и фильтры не понадобятся. Но чаще используют фильтры. Во-первых, потому что они входят в стандарт и описаны во всех книжках. Во-вторых, они более просты в применении, понимании и отладке.

Comment: Очень сочно раскрыли применение, спасибо:)